# Some but not all LaTeX rendering correctly on tools page

Tags: bug, status-review, mathjax, 10k-tools

Users with sufficiently high reputation have access to a "tools" page, which I like a lot. However, sometimes I find that the $\rm\TeX$ doesn't render properly. What is particularly puzzling is that sometimes *some* of the $\rm\TeX$ will render fine, but some of it will not.  For example, in the screenshot below, note that in the upper left, $y^3 = x^4 + x+1$ renders fine, but elsewhere the raw $\rm\TeX$ is displayed.  I am using Firefox 91.5 if that matters. At first I thought that maybe the browser was just taking a long time to process the MathJax, but the problem does not seem to resolve itself no matter how long I wait.

[image: MO tools page]

Comment: Yes, this also happens on my end.

Comment: These lists are not included in the HTML as sent, they are populated dynamically with Javascript after the page is loaded. Perhaps there is a race condition that makes some of them load before MathJax processing, but some of them it finishes.

Comment: A [bit of searching](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5B10k-tools%5D+%5Bmathjax%5D) also leads to this question on [meta.se]: [Render MathJax in the 10k tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209393). (It's from 2013. Although it's not the same, I'd certainly consider it related.)

Comment: Should the image be edited to obscure information that might not be intended to be visible to users with sub-10k reputation?

Comment: @LSpice Other than the general appearance of the page, I don't see information in the image that users with sub-10k reputation have no access to. For example, the scores of the individual questions are all publicly visible. They can't *easily* figure out what the highest-scoring question of the day is, but they could in principle figure it out.